# How can I remove a small border on the left of an image?

Tags: space, alignment

This is my first time posting on this site. I've used it to help troubleshoot numerous issues, but today, I have a very... simple issue that I cant seem to fix.

Picture of the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOyWR.png

As you can see, there is a bit of a space between the left side of the page and the start of the lower part. Here is the code I used to accomplish what I have so far

```
<head>
<title>
<?php include 'config.php';
echo $pagetitle;
?>
</title>
<style>
body{
background-image:url(images/bg.png);
background-repeat:repeat;
z-index:1;
}
div#content{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
   <img src="images/lower.png" style="max-width:100%; left:0; max-height:100% z-index:2;">
</div>
```

So, basically, my question is, how do I remove that small edge of the background peeking in front of the lower image.

@Richard Andrew Lee Got it, I feel really stupid. I just added left: -10; to #content. Thanks man!

Comment: left:-10px?? is this supposed to scale? if you could post a fiddle that would be even better. looks like padding.

Answer (score 0):

Oh!!!! sorry, i didnt get it, haha, to make up for it, here is an edited copy of the image, http://trevorrudolph.com/new.png

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, however, seems to still not work.